# Messaging system jquery sends jQuery514109241_1210239812938 when I put :)) in the message

Tags: javascript, jquery

When I put ":))" in my textarea and send via ajax, it inputs into the database a value like
"jQuery172039628539560362697_1345324072488", how can I stop this? Should I parse my text in some way in javascript first to make it recognize it's text, and not part of the javascript coding?

This is how i get my text

```
var message = $("textarea.message_thread").val();
var dataString = 'id=' + id + '&message=' + message;
// make ajax call
```

sending with

```
$.ajax( 
                        {  
                            type: "POST",  
                            url: "/inbox/instsend",  
                            data: dataString,
                            dataType: 'json',
                            success: function(results) {}

                        }
```

Comment: How are you sending the AJAX request?

Comment: Updated question, with codes.

Comment: Where is the *database* SQL part? That's where the problem is occurring.

Comment: You're also sending a URL-encoded string, *not* JSON. Let jQuery encode your data, give `data: myDataObj`.

Comment: the database part is fine, I checked the inserts, the problem occurs on initial pass to variables in php. 
@JaredFarrish I'm sneding a url-encoded string, ok so instead of dataString I have to put myDataObj, and it will know datastring = myDataObj?

Comment: Try `dataString = {id: id, message: message};` where you have the url encoded version.

Comment: Worked like a charm!!! Thank you!! I have to go over all my javascript now, since I haven't been doing that -_-", so always use dataString = { id: id, message: message } format everywhere too? This is the "correct way" in most/all situations? Go ahead and post this as the answer so I could accept it :D

Comment: Oh lord; we've created a monster. NO, do NOT just sprinkle it everywhere. You need to understand your constructs. When you submit AJAX and have the `dataType: 'json'`, what you submit data-wise has to be JSON-izable. Check for *that* condition. You don't have to, or want to, do it everywhere.

Comment: Monster shot down. So only where it's dataType: 'json'. Got it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See the comments under the question; the problem is that what has been submitted in `dataString` is actually a url-encoded string, and not a JSON-izable or JSON literal variable.

Hence:

```
dataString = {id: id, message: message};
```

Will fix this problem, here. jQuery will take that object-initialized variable and encode it for you to JSON.

Answer (score 0):

This is done automatically by jQuery when you're using JSONP for cross-domain AJAX calls. It should be sending this string as the value of the `callback` parameter.

Comment: everything is done in beta.mysite.com , no cross domain calls. I updated my question with my code on how i get the text.

Answer (score 0):

You need to sanitise the input and escape any control codes - e.g. : and )

Answer (score 0):

Since you are doing POST here. This would work

```
var dataString = '{'+'id:' + id + 'message:' + message +'}'
```

Comment: var dataString = '{'+'id:' + id + 'message:' + message +'}'
i updated the answer in post we do not send parameter with ampersand but in we send in this format

Comment: You're missing a comma in there, too.

Comment: And, really, it does *not* have to be a string: `{id: id, message: message}`

Comment: The point is not that there is a typo, it's that you are attempting to manually write json. `var dataString = {id: id, message: message};` is equivalent, less hacky and more robust

Comment: I'm with @AD7six, That's kind've a silly way of doing it (and *still* missing a comma); the object initializer would be *way* easier and, let's face it, *more fun*.